# Getting text using span id error

Tags: vb.net

I want to grab the text from the span id "hkoTemp"
and here is the code:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim wb As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser
    wb.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.hko.gov.hk/contentc.htm"))
    Dim temp = wb.Document.GetElementById("hkoTemp").GetAttribute("innerText")
    MsgBox(temp)
    End Sub
```

When i try to run it, it will have a error on 
`Dim temp = wb.Document.GetElementById("hkoTemp").GetAttribute("innerText")`

how can i fix it?

Comment: What is ***that error***? My best guess is you are not finding the element `hkoTemp`. I would see if it found anything first as if not you won't have any attributes either. `If wb.Document.GetElementById("hkoTemp") IsNot Nothing Then ...` then if you have something try after the attributes next...

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim wb As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser()
    wb.AllowNavigation = True
    AddHandler wb.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf wb_DocumentCompleted)
    wb.Navigate(New Uri("http://www.hko.gov.hk/contentc.htm"))
End Sub

Private Sub wb_DocumentCompleted(sender As Object, e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    ' wb.Document is not null at this point
    Dim wb As WebBrowser = sender
    Dim temp = wb.Document.GetElementById("hkoTemp").GetAttribute("innerText")
    MsgBox(temp)
End Sub
```